# How to detect swipe position in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm building a jQuery Mobile app and I'm in need of a way to track a user's finger movement during a swipe event. I've found [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/), which seems to offer this functionality in their `swipemove` event, but I was hoping to not have to import another library. Does the jQuery Mobile `swipe` event return this kind of information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with the jQM only. I have created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/cnuGy/. I have tested it in the Windows Firefox, Android 4.1 stack browser and iPad.

```
$('#index').on('touchstart vmousedown', function(){
    $('#start').val('Touch start');
})

$('#index').on('touchmove vmousemove', function(event){
    $('#move-x').val(event.pageX);
    $('#move-y').val(event.pageY);
})

$('#index').on('touchend vmouseup', function(){
    $('#end').val('Touch end');
});
```

V events like vmousedown are working only with mouse, while touch events work on touch devices (iPad, Android...).

Comment: Does this take any resource to listen after those events? Or is it more what kind of functions you binds to the event that's important?

Comment: This is great. Saved my day. Please update from `.live` to `.on`